# MySQL to MySQLi semicolon issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've created an intranet several years ago and was using mysql extension. I am now converting it to the mysqli extension. Everything was going fine until I ran into this issue;

I commented the old query line using mysql which was working fine. I then made a copy-paste of it, remove the comment statement and made changes for mysqli, like I did several times now, saved and when I open up the page, nothing works, nothing prints. A blank page.

I then manually retyped the query under, commented the non-working one, and it worked. Now if I do the opposite, it doesn't work. If I compare the two lines, they are exactly the same, one works, the other one doesn't. I then copied from the working line to the non-working line every string of character and checked if it was still working, everything came from the working line, and it didn't work. I did every character except the ending semicolon..., then I proceeded to copy the ending semicolon from the working line to the non working line, saved, and it worked..., so somehow, the semicolon in the non working line is not 'the same' as the one in the working line, but in appearance, the character is exactly the same, no difference at all.

Here's a copy of the 2 lines;

```
$query = mysqli_query($link,$querystring) or die(mysqli_error($link)); //This line IS NOT working

$query = mysqli_query($link,$querystring) or die(mysqli_error($link)); //This line IS working
```

Both query's are reffering to the same `$querystring` value, so `$querystring` is not at fault since it works for one of them.

I get no error messages whatsoever, just a blank page starting from where the query is.

My page is UTF-8 encoded.

If I even make a copy paste from that semicolon into notepad and then make another copy-paste from Notepad to the non working request, it doesn't work.

If I make the same thing to notepad from the working query to the non working query, it will work.

I'm completely clueless, I know I can say 'ok, it works by deleting the semicolon and typing it again', but I have several hundreds if not thousands of requests in the intranet, will some requests works while others don't? It's the first time I'm aware of this. And this is not telling why it does this?

Someone has a clue on why it does that??!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check your PHP error log.

Comment: First, make sure that it is not a caching issue. Is your server using aggressive caching? It might be the case. Also, check if the semi-colon is in fact the standard semi-colon: some other languages (like Chinese Mandarin) have different unicode character for the same semi-colon symbol, which causes the script to err out.

Comment: Your only getting a blank page with no errors because you don't have error reporting on in your php.ini. Check the log or turn on errors.

Comment: This is what I get when turning on error reporting and in my apache log : PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING. I know that the ending semicolon is the issue, but why it is doing this, it is a proper semicolon after all, and it was 'working' with my previous mysql query, why not now?!?

Comment: Try to copy paste both characters into http://asciivalue.com/ probably you'll see that characters are not the same

Comment: I just did that with asciivalue.com website..., they gave me the same results, which is 59 3B 73 (Dec Hex Oct)

Answer (score 1):

Its a greek question mark

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#Greek_question_mark

looks like a semicolon but its not, its illegal in javascript, and it seems doesn't terminate a PHP statement.

Comment: That would make sense, but does someone knows 

1) How to detect Greek question marks from semicolon (I use Ultra-Edit 25.10 and my file is properly UTF-8 encoded)

2) How I ended up possibly typing a greek encoded character there? I use US keyboard.

3) Why it was working with my mysql statement and now not working with my mysqli statement...., if it's a greek question mark, wouldn't it failed too with the mysql statement?

Answer (score 0):

Well well, how strange is that.

I've been on that website : [Charset Decoder](http://www.webatic.com/run/chars/charset_decoder.php) and I have pasted both of my semicolon in there, here are the results for the 'ANSI charset' on the right (ISO 8859-1).

Working semicolon = ;

Non working semicolon = ï»¿;

I was using Ultra-Edit for programming and i was showing the exact same line, even after copying and pasting it back and forth into notepad, still the same thing.

I'm also using my Chromebox for programming and I'm using Codeanywhere as my text editor and here is what I saw on the non working line... (see image) [Picture of file open in Codeanywhere](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LF8S-QilmQ4ul4QM7UQzyWi4cD1LunrB/view?usp=drivesdk)

[Picture of file open in Codeanywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5jaA.jpg)

So basically, the web editor Codeanywhere was able to actually see a 'problem' with the semicolon and was notifying me by adding a red dot before the semicolon, to him, the character used was not the same and the website 'Charset decoder' confirmed that.

This is really strange I thought a whole file was encoded in a character set and not individual characters inside a file could use different charset..., or maybe I don't understand at all how charsets works...